# Find probability that first 50 balls taken from urn are white.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Urn contains two balls white and black. Paul takes ball every time from urn until it is black. Also when he takes white, he returns that to urn and also two more white balls are added. Find probability that first 50 balls taken from urn are white.

My work.

If first one is white than probability is $1/2$. Second time if you add 2 white balls it becomes $3/4$. So $1/2 \times3/4 \times 5/6 \times \cdots$ but answer is $\frac{100!}{2^{100}(50!)^2}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think what you are doing is wrong?  Just because the answer looks different?  Have you considered the possibility that the answers are the same but just written in different ways?

Comment: Notice that $2\times 4\times 6\times 8 = (2\times 1)\times (2\times 2)\times (2\times 3)\times (2\times 4) = 2^4\times (1\times 2\times 3\times 4) = 2^4\cdot 4!$.  Now... generalize and you can find how to simplify "doublefactorials" into ordinary factorials with powers of two.

Comment: As for the numerator... recognize that $1\times 3\times 5\times 7 = \dfrac{1\times 2\times 3\times 4\times 5\times 6\times 7\times 8}{2\times 4\times 6\times 8}$ and use what you learned about $2\times 4\times 6\times 8$ from the previous comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collating comments and giving the punchline:

The notation $n!$ with $n$ a natural number is shorthand for $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n k = 1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times n$ and is referred to as a "factorial"

The notation $(2n)!!$ with $n$ a natural number is shorthand for $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n 2k = 2\times 4\times 6\times \cdots \times (2n)$ and is referred to as a "double factorial" and can be seen by factoring a common factor of $2$ from every term to be equal to $2^n(n!)$

Similarly, $(2n-1)!!$ refers to $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (2k-1) = 1\times 3\times 5\times \cdots \times (2n-1)$.  This too can be simplified.  Start by both multiplying and dividing by $(2n)!!$, recognize the top as a factorial, and perform the same simplification from the previous to get the bottom simplified to see $(2n-1)!! = \dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{n}(n!)}$

Your answer you found was $$\frac{1\times 3\times 5\times \cdots \times 99}{2\times 4\times 6\times \cdots \times 100} = \dfrac{99!!}{100!!}$$

Simplifying with what we talked about earlier:

$$\frac{99!!}{100!!} = \frac{100!}{2^{100}(50!)^2}$$

Comment: Respected Mr. Moravitz, can this problem be solved through binoms $\binom{n}{m}$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov not in any sort of convenient fashion

Comment: Only how have you suggested?